# Generated: not cached yet (either no one has visited the page recently, or something is preventing the cache from being generated).

Tags: caching, proxies

I just spin a test Drupal7 site and having some issue w/ getting boost module to work(

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
$ uname -a
Linux XXX.XXXXX.XXX 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 16 11:13:47 CDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ rpm -q drupal7 php php-pecl-apc
drupal7-7.23-3.el6.noarch
php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64
$ drush -r /usr/share/drupal7/ -l alexustest pm-list | grep '(boost)'
Performance and scalability  Boost (boost)                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-beta2 
$
```

this is what I get via "Boost: Pages cache status" block:

> File: cache/normal/alexustest/_.html
>
> Generated: not cached yet (either no one has visited the page
>   recently, or something is preventing the cache from being generated).

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please logout, visit same page as anoymous user then login and visit again. I think you can see cached page message.

Comment: I sometimes get following: `This page will not be cached: Core Drupal dynamic pages`.